# Проблемы с парсингом html Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qnetworkrequest

Я пробую спарсить страницу с помощью QNetworkAccessManager, Но просто получить страницу мне недостаточно, мне нужно выполнить некий JS код на этой странице, после чего по идее страница обновляется с необходимой мне информацией, и уже эту страницу мне необходимо получить, какими методами это можно реализовать, перешерстил документацию, но ничего путного не нашел, может что то упустил, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого библиотека предоставляет привязки к [CEF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework), а именно [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html). Подпишитесь на сигнал `QWebEngineView::loadFinished(bool)` и выполните JavaScript код по аналогии с `<a href="javascript: alert('Hello, world!')">eval js</a>`. Пример кода:

```
QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
connect(view, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, [&]() {
    view->load(QUrl("javascript:location.hash = 'value'"));
});
connect(view, &QWebEngineView::urlChanged, [&]() {
    QString url = view.url().toString(); 
    if(url.indexOf("#")!=-1) {
        qDebug() << "Value:" << url.split("#").at(1);
    }
});
view->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
view->show();
```

Для получения значения можно сделать вывод в location.hash - значение, хранимое в ссылке после символа #. Более подробно об этом можно прочитать [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp). При изменении текущего адреса выбрасывается сигнал `QWebEngineView::urlChanged(const QUrl)`